# Quickly checking associativity of a possible group action

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, associativity

In *Artin, Algebra*, the author says that it is usually clear in a given example of a group action that the axioms for it hold. The simplest example given is the action of the group $\{1,r\}$ on $\mathbb{C}$ given by $rz = \bar{z}$.

The identity axiom for a group action is trivial. However, to verify associativity, I don't see an easier way than brute force.

In this case the only non-trivial element is $r$ so since identity function commutes with any other, we only need to check 3 cases. It still feels like a lot of work for something that should be clear. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Do you accept $\Bbb Z_2$ has an associative addition operation?

Comment: @runway44 yes, how does that help tho?

Comment: It follows from $\bar{\bar{z}} = z$ (i.e. the action of $z$ on ${\mathbb C}$ is a permutation of order $2$).